# getting all ImageFields associated with a node

Tags: drupal, imagefield

How do i get all the image fields attached to a content type on a full node without knowing the field names? Just out of curiosity, is there a way we can get all the fields of a specific type?

I am developing a module that needs image fields tied to a specific node and i'm using hook_node_view for fetching the node data.

I already viewed following post and it seems pretty relevant but i had difficulty understanding.

[How to get the first image field from a node without knowing the field's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656595/how-to-get-the-first-image-field-from-a-node-without-knowing-the-fields-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i finally found the function i was looking for and it was pretty simple. All i had to do was to get all the fields `field_info_instances()` with `$entity_type` as the first parameter and then iterating over the result to get the widget type 'image_image' for ImageFields.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by checking all the fields of your content type & check its "type" field

if the type field is a image you can render it